# How to detect whether front or rear camera is active; Find camera resolution programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to detect two things programmatically :

i used divcam 3rd party library not the image picker

1. How to detect which camera is active (Front/Rear)
2. How to detect camera resolution

I need to implement logic based on these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `UIImagePickerController` there is a propery called `cameraDevice` which returns `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice`  which has possible values viz- `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront` and `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear`.

may use something like --

```
if(aPickerInstance.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront){
   //Front cam
}else{
   //Rear Cam
}
```

Comment: i used divcam not the image picker